# Armature permanently in wireframe view

Tags: armature, edit-mode

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I was experimenting with armatures when suddenly it went into what I think is wireframe mode but I can't seem to change it. I think I might've accidentally pressed a shortcut, but I have no idea how to fix this.

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off the X-Ray feature on the top of the 3D viewport display setting/menu:

[image: xrayoff]